# After my laptop wakes up from sleeping/hibernating, the LCD/brightness is very low. How can I set it to default?

Tags: linux, debian, lcd

In Power Management Preferences, On AC Power tab, I have brightness to 100%. "Dim display when idle" is not checked.

I know for sure my LCD brightness is capable of going higher, because if I hit `Fn` and `F7` then it resets the monitor brightness and settings for a few seconds, but the resolution breaks and then the brightness goes back.

PS: OS is Debian Lenny ( I set the tags but for clarification ) and laptop is a Thinkpad.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Debian Lenny ( linux )

Comment: duh, it would help if I looked at tags, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I found the right key by putting my laptop keys under a bright light.. `Fn` + `Home` does it ( and `End` is for dim ).

FYI: Selecting this answer as soon as I can ( 2 day minimum it seems )